# Django ImportError: cannot import name 'views'

Tags: python, django

The command `python3 manage.py makemigrations projectxap` keeps returning the import error. `ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'projectxproject'`.

I have tried different variation of importing the views  e.g `from projectxapp import views` ,  `import views` and   `from projectxapp.views import *` but i keep getting the same error.

Here is my folder structure and code.

[image: File structure and code]

Comment: I think you are actually using `Views` for package name instead of `views`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a views in projectxproject folder which is the folder where urls.py is located. If you want to get the Views from projectxapp folder you must have a urls.py inside your app (projectxapp folder) and then use the view

In your projectxproject urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('/admin', admin.site.urls),
    path('/projectxapp', include('projectxapp.urls')),
]
```

You have to add a ulrs folder in projectxapp and in there:

```
from Views.(the name of the file) import (the name of the view)
```